# How to make image only website friendly to googlebot?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, images, googlebot, text

so I making this portfolio site for some artist. She draw all the menus and texts manually(on paper), then scanned, some "post processing" in photoshop and that's how the whole layout was created.

Now the problem is all texts are actually images so bots can't read this. How to make this site more friendly to google bot so it can actually gather some data?

Some ideas are:

- put text in alt, title tags (sometimes text is too long I guess)
- some additional texts in footer
- comments
- found this: [How do I get images containing text to be indexed by search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/how-do-i-get-images-containing-text-to-be-indexed-by-search-engines) good idea?
- also thought of normal text and than hiding it in javascript (googlebot doesn't execute js, does it?)

Thanks for all answers

P.S. I know it's bad idea, to create web page like this, I know about embed fonts but it's really specific case, so I hope you'll understand my problem:)

Comment: This question is not a complete duplicate of the other question.  The other question asks about images that contain text, this question is about an entire site (chrome and text).

Comment: @Stephen, exactly:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the text on the site normally, but then use the images with the same text in them to cover up the text on the page.  I found this post on StackOverflow which has a technique for doing so that you could use: [Is there a foreground equivalent to background-image in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12659953/is-there-a-foreground-equivalent-to-background-image-in-css)

Comment: Isn't it a little bit like some black seo methods with adding invisible text (full of keywords for example)? But I guess most solutions are, because that's the point - to hide the text... I'm not gonna get banned by google, right?

Comment: It could be a way of hiding text that could get a site banned.  I've never heard of Google checking for text hidden *under* anything before.  If they do automated checks, the site could get banned.  I believe your intent would get you passed a manual review in this case.

Comment: If the text is so incredibly stylised that no font will do (although you could perhaps roll your own?) then a standard image replacement technique is probably the way to go - it's the way we always used to do it. However, this will be OK for small bits of text/titles etc. If you are dealing with large blocks of copy then it is probably not a good idea - but who wants to read large blocks of "whacky" text?